# Class Constructor to initialize vector of vector

Tags: c++, class, vector

I want initialize a vector of vector of bool inside my costructor.

This is my class:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(const OtherClass&g):
        g(g), count(g.node_count(), std::vector<bool>(16))){}


private:
    const OtherClass&g;
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>>count;
};
```

but when I try to initialize `count` I obtain this error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<std::vector<bool> >) (int)’
```

Comment: Unrelated, [try to avoid](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool) `vector<bool>`, it's a hybrid monster. You can use [`std::bitset<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead.

Comment: strange why use a vector if you know that you need 16 bool ? and why `const OtherClass&` ? Trouble incoming with this design. When you give a reference of an object(A) to an other object(B) this object(A) should belong to him(B) so why `const` ? (maybe you don't want to modify him, so it's ok)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [fill constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/). If you don't use c++ 11 you need to specify the default value for elements in the vector `count(g.node_count(), std::vector<bool>(16, true))`

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to ask if you know that `vector<bool>` is a special type of vector with a bit different implementation because of optimisation, which can cause a bit different behaviour in some cases.

If you want to use it, you must pass to constructor `vector<bool>(16, true)` filling it with 16 true values.